# How to apply Angular component from string

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to apply html component in existing application.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ng-container> {{html}} </ng-container>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  html = '<my-app></my-app>';
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my',
  template: `<span>{{name}}</span>`
})
export class MyComponent  {
  name = 'test';
}
```

it writes screen `"<my-app></my-app>"` but it should be `"test"`

[working application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5hv9w)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311330/angular-5-bind-a-component-selector-with-innerhtml

Comment: it won't work like that, unless you use angular elements https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like with Angular. Maybe if you use angular elements.

### Using angular elements

First thing you need to do is bind the html using `[innerHtml]` binding on some element. You also need to mark the html as trusted https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer. Once you have done this a `my-app` element will be added to the DOM but this is not an angular component. If you use angular elements, it will get turned into a component. The downside is that all the interactions with a dynamic created component (via html) will need to be via the dom element. The upside is that now you can create your angular components from anywhere, including jQuery, angular Js or what ever.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elements-dynamic?file=app/custom-elements/custom-hello.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'custom-hello',
  template: `
  <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
  <div [innerHtml]="test"></div>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class CustomHelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
  ) {
  }

  test = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<my-test-component name="dynamic"></my-test-component>');
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-test-component',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>`,
  styles: []
})
export class MyTestComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

### Loading dynamic components by ref in a ViewContainer

The angular way of showing a dynamic component is below as documented here (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) but you will need the component reference, not the selector (and the component needs to be in the module's `entryComponentes`):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dyn-component?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[container-ref]',
})
export class ContainerRefDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ng-template container-ref></ng-template>`
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild(ContainerRefDirective, { static: true })
  container: ContainerRefDirective;

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const componentFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(MyComponent);
    const viewContainerRef = this.container.viewContainerRef;
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my',
  template: `<span>{{name}}</span>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  name = 'test';
}
```

Comment: You are using MyComponent class to resolve. But my components are from different modusle. So I do not know name of classes. I need compile and ad it to the applcation like angularjs. Angular is bigger than angularjs. So why can not I do this?

Comment: As I said, you need to create custom elements (or standard web custom components) in order to work like that. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elements-dynamic?file=app/custom-elements/custom-hello.component.ts

Comment: it does not work https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elements-dynamic?file=app/custom-elements/custom-hello.component.ts

Comment: @barteloma it does work for me (on Chrome, other browsers may have a hard time)...

Comment: Ok internet Explorer issue. But `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<my-test-component name="dynamic"></my-test-component>')` parameter is static hard coded component string. I am getting is from binding as a variable. So it did not worked for me.

Comment: @barteloma it works for received variables as well. You just need to call `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`.

Comment: @Andrie similar code does not work. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5hv9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @barteloma as I said, you need to use angular custom elements. Check the module and the bootstrap file. https://angular.io/guide/elements